# ERROR AL QUERER SUMAR EN PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy seguro que para muchos de ustedes esta debe ser una solucion basica, Pero estoy aprendiendo en esto de python.

Cree una funcion en donde quiero que la persona con un input pueda ingresar valores y guardarlos en una lista para luego poder sumarlos. Mi idea de esto es que la persona pueda sumar varios numeros antes de obtener su resultado y no limitarse a solo sumar 2 o 3 valores. Y cuando la persona decida querer sumar que pueda tecrear "sumar" para hacer la operacion y que muestre la pantalla.

Mi problema esta en que al momento en que la persona teclea "sumar" para que se realice la operacion de suma de los digitos que haya ingresado en la lista, este se agrega a la lista como un string en vez de sumarse. Me parece raro esto ya que estoy ocupando if y elif...

[image: Aqui mi codigo Fuente]

Comment: Tenías un `if numeros == numeros`. Esa condición siempre va a ser cierta (una variable es siempre igual a sí misma). Por eso te entraba por ese `if`  y nunca llegaba a considerar el `elif`  que tenías después. Supongo que querías decir `if numeros.is_digit()`

Comment: Si hubieras publicado el código como texto (no como imagen), ya te habría dado la solución, pero no me voy a dar el trabajo de retipear todo tu código.

Comment: Gracias amigo. Soy nuevo en start overflow. tendre en cuenta lo que dices con respecto a como publicar el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

En python el operador `+` es utilizado para sumar y también para concatenar `strings` (Cadenas de caracteres), por eso concatena la palabra suma

Puedes revisar si el valor de `numeros` es un número o no con `isdigit()`

Ten en cuenta que el valor de `input` por defecto es un `string` por lo que debes convertirlo a valor numérico para poder sumar, de otra forma te va a concatenar los valores. puedes utilizar la función `int()`

Aquí está el ejemplo completo funcionando:

```
def sumavarios():
  lista = []
  while True:
    numeros = input("""Ingresa los números a sumar, o escribe "sumar" si ya deseas sumar: """)
    if numeros.isdigit():
      lista.append(int(numeros))
      print("\nNumeros a sumar hasta ahora", lista)
    elif numeros == "sumar":
      misuma = sum(lista)
      print(misuma)
      break

sumavarios()
```

Comment: Gracias amigo. Funciono para mi...Muy agradecidoooo !!!

Comment: No funciona con números negativos ("-1") ni valores en punto flotante ("1.1").

Answer (score 0):

Convierte los números en enteros cuando los vas a guardar. Algo como esto:

```
lista.append(int(numeros))
```

Comment: no funciono para mi. arriba comente  y pegue foto del error.... es como si no pasara a la condicion de elif..